# Fetch values alternately from mysql table having different foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables given below

**Classes**

```
classid int autoincrement primary key
classname varchar
```

**Students**

```
studentid int autoincrement primary key
studentname varchar
classid int foreign key references classes
```

I want fetch studentid from table students from selected classes alternately in a single query. If selected classids are 1,2,3 then i want studentid from classid 1 then 2 then 3 again start from 1 then 2 then 3 again start from 1 and so on. How can i write the query to get the result like

```
                studentid               classid
                  id1                      1
                  id2                      2
                  id3                      3
                  id4                      1
                  id5                      2
                  id6                      3
                  id7                      1
```

Comment: Please elaborate the question with sample data and expected result

Comment: would you please give the **output table** as you want

Answer (score 0):

Through Queryt I don't know but you can do the way like,

fire query and you will got all Ids to fetch alternatively, say it is [5, 9, 10].
totalNumberOfIdsYouGot = 3 (total size of array here)

```
for(int i=0; i<numberOfTimesItShouldIterate; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<totalNumberOfIdsYouGot.length; j++){
        //Here fire single Query, change only ids each time as totalNumberOfIdsYouGot[j]           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this in Mysql. Oracle as a connect by statement, through which you can achive this. 
 
I think you will need to use a procedure to populate the table with this result. and then select

 
You can use two cursors and achieve this inside `Stored Procedure`